# python print work but can't return

Tags: python, return

```
def meiju(num,chesslist=range(16),result=[],finalresult=[]):
    if num==1:
        for x in range(len(chesslist)):
            result.append(chesslist[x])
            nes=[nest for nest in result]
            finalresult.append(nes)
            if len(chesslist)==1:
                print finalresult         #work
                return finalresult        #don't work
            result.pop()
    else:
        for y in range(len(chesslist)):
            result.append(chesslist[y])
            meiju(num-1,chesslist[y+1:],result,finalresult)
            result.pop()
print meiju(2)
```

`print finalresult` can work,but the next line `return finalresult` can't work.

in fact i add `print finalresult` statement for testing.

Comment: why do you want to return the finalresult?

Comment: `print` will print out a value and `return` will return that value from the function. I don't understand your question, print works but return doesn't work? What do you mean?

Comment: he means print prints the value and return does not print the value AKA what u just said

Comment: So I just debugged your code, after it returns, it goes immediately to the else and pops everything from result, returning None

Comment: Since you are calling the function recursively, the return doesn't work because it has to finish the previous calls, before it can actually return a value. Think of it as a boxes. One box calls another, and that box calls another. Once you're at the end, its all returned to the beginning along with a value. Since, you're popping the values off, you end up with None. I would try to draw out what you are trying to do and rework the logic.

Comment: oh maybe I know why.thanks

Comment: `finalresult=[]`: bad idea.  That will NOT create a new empty list on each call, it creates a single list at compile time which is then reused on subsequent calls.